# Insert a new record with join tables in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a simple project where I define 2 models and the join between them. I omitted all the useless fields for the question but there is a key in every table.

```
public class Article : Table
{
    [JsonPropertyName("body")]
    [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)]
    public string? Body { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("tags")]
    [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)]
    public virtual ICollection<Tag>? Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag : Table
{
    [JsonPropertyName("name")]
    [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)]
    public string? Name { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("articles")]
    [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)]
    public virtual ICollection<Article>? Articles { get; set; }
}
```

The common `Table` is defined

```
public class Table : ITable
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long ID { get; set; }
}
```

Using `Entity Framework Core` in an ASP.NET Core application based on NET7, 3 tables have been created: `Article`, `Tags` and `ArticleTag` (that I haven't defined). The table `ArticleTag` has 2 fields (as you can imagine): *ArticleId* and *TagsId*.

I understand the purpose: an article can have more than one tag. So, this table links the two tables in a many-to-many relation. Also, it is what I want to do.

When the application starts, the database is created but also there is a seed for `Tags`. I want to use only those tags.

[image]

Based on this model, I created the `POST` API that receives the json for an `Article` and saves it in the database.

[image]

The function to save in the database is generic

```
public async Task<T> AddAsync(T entity)
{
    await _db.Set<T>().AddAsync(entity);
    await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

    return entity;
}
```

When I call the API with a valid json, with all the data and the list of the tags with all details, I get an error

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred
> while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
>
> ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'tbl_Tags' when
> IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
>
> at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
> Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>
> at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
> exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>
> at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
> stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)

Obviously, I understand the error. It is not possible to add the same tag again and this is fine. So, how can I fix the issue?

Do I have to split the request in the API and create the `Article` first and then add the record in the `ArticleTag`? How can I add new records to the `ArticleTag` whilst I don't have a model for this table? Do I Have to add a model for the `ArticleTag` table?

Comment: you have omitted the important part of the code - how your entity key is defined. It can probably be fixed with `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]`

Comment: You're making a huge mistake by re-using EF entity classes as DTOs. Don't do it. Define separate classes for your DTOs (and that's the cause of the error too: your DTO has a property mapped to the `IDENTITY` (autonumber) column in the table - which is an incorrect design because clients can't define meaningful values for that column. Do you see the problem now?

Comment: @YehorAndrosov I added the definition of `Table` that is a common model for all the tables

Comment: @Dai honestly I can't see the problem. I thought I could use the `Domain` definition as EF classes and DTOs in order to have clean code and less mapping. Otherwise, I have to duplicate the classes and in the EF classes only add the decorations for the database. Also, if I split DTOs and EF classes, how can I have access to the autogenerated class `ArticleTags`?

Comment: _"Also, if I split DTOs and EF classes, how can I have access to the autogenerated class ArticleTags?"_ - What do you mean by this?

Comment: _"I have to duplicate the classes and in the EF classes only add the decorations for the database"_ - the situation is not _that bad_: you can use Roslyn code-generation to auto-generate DTOs class definitions from EF class definitions (and coresponding TypeScript `.d.ts` too).

Comment: @Dai Do you have any example/document on how to use Roslyn for that? Why do I need TypeScripts? Does it create also the mapping?

Comment: EF generates 3 tables (Articles, Tags and ArticleTag) from 2 classes (Article and Tag). The 3rd table connects the articles with the tags. How can I add records here?

Comment: @Enrico https://amanagrawal.blog/2021/07/28/using-c-sharp-source-generators-to-generate-dtos-part2/

Comment: @Dai Source Generator makes me crazy! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77164556/source-generator-is-ignored-by-visual-studio